# How does one programmatically create a topic w/ hornet q?

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I have been looking at the org.hornetq.core.server package which seems to have the most interesting low level APIS relating to managing the server.

The server session has a few methods labelled something Queue but none include Topic ...

**ServerSession**

```
void createQueue(SimpleString address,
                          SimpleString name,
                          SimpleString filterString,
                          boolean temporary,
                          boolean durable) throws Exception;

   void deleteQueue(SimpleString name) throws Exception
```

interface **QueueFactory**

```
Queue createQueue(long persistenceID,
                 final SimpleString address,
                 SimpleString name,
                 Filter filter,
                 boolean durable,
                 boolean temporary);
```

However i could not figure out how to create a topic. Am i missing something is a JMS topic implemented as a queue ?

Comment: Are you using JMS, or just the low-level hornetQ API?

Comment: I am avoiding the JMS layer and sticking to the core "native/core" HornetQ API.

Comment: Oh well.. because I know how to do it in the JMS layer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core API does not know the concept of a Topic as it is used in JMS, it only knows queues and adresses. In the [documentation](http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.1.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/using-core.html) it says:

*For example, a JMS topic would *be* implemented by a single address to which many queues are bound. Each queue represents a subscription of the topic. A JMS Queue would be implemented as a single address to which one queue is bound - that queue represents the JMS queue.*

You could implement it with the core API the same way or just use JMS :-)